# Windows Kernel Objects

Tags: oop, kernel, kernel32

Is the notion of kernel object (pipe, socket, mutex, ...) in windows linked to the notion of object in Object Oriented Programming (*in oop, an object has attributes and methods attached to it*)?

Answer (score 0):

Although main parts of the kernel are written in pure C, implementation of the kernel objects in Windows follows some OOP principles. Certain operations are supported by all types of kernel objects which can be viewed in a way that all kernel object share the same ancestor (e.g. similar to Object in Java). Such operations include opening the object and setting/querying its security setttings.

There is a special type of kernel object called **Object type** the purpose of which is to describe characteristics shared by a given type of kernel object (e.g. processes, semaphores, open registry keys...). Such characteristics include the following:

1. size of the object body (a memory block hodling an instance of the object),
2. whether the object body is allocated from paged (swappable to disk) or nonpaged (always resident) memory,
3. whether the object supports waiting (mostly used by synchronization objects, but also by processes or threads (these objects enter signaled state when they finish their work),
4. (virtual) destructor,
5. a (virtual) procedure responsible for working with object's security descriptor,
6. and more.

Since each kernel object contains a reference to its type object (including the type objects themselves – there is a special type object describing type objects), and since the type object define several callbacks implemented by the individual instances of type objects (processes, threads etc.), we can say that the implementation of Windows kernel objects utilizes the polymorphism and the inheritance principles. The encapsulation principle is also present because the kernel exports various high-level routines working with individual types of objects (`NtXxxProcess`, `NtXxxFile`...).

There also exists many types of "objects" that are not based on the general kernel object implementation. Most of the GUI objects (windows, brlushes, bitmaps, ...) fall into this category, with exception of desktops and window stations. Most of the kernel objects is implemented by the main kernel module (`ntoskrnl.exe`), although an undocumented interface (`ObCreateObjectType`) allowing to implement your own type objects, exists.

To sum this answer up: the implementation of Windows kernel objects does use OOP principles but keep in mind that the kernel is written in C that has no native support for OOP constructs.